# How can I exit the if with a return?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

I have a problem when I run my application bot. I can't leave the if statement. I think it's because I haven't done a return but I don't know how to structure it in a function like that, can someone help me?

```
     private async Task OpcionCostoCUV(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var message = await result as Activity;

        if ((message.Text.Equals("1.- CUV Residencial")) || (message.Text.Equals("1.- cuv residencial")) || (message.Text.Equals("1.- CUV RESIDENCIAL")) || (message.Text.Equals("1"))
            || (message.Text.Equals("1.-")) || (message.Text.Equals("CUV residencial")) || (message.Text.Equals("cuv residencial")) || (message.Text.Equals("CUV RESIDENCIAL"))
            || (message.Text.Equals("2.- CUV de Interes Social")) || (message.Text.Equals("2.- cuv de interes Social")) || (message.Text.Equals("2.- CUV DE INTERES SOCIAL")) || (message.Text.Equals("2"))
            || (message.Text.Equals("2.-")) || (message.Text.Equals("CUV de Interes Social")) || (message.Text.Equals("cuv de interes Social")) || (message.Text.Equals("CUV DE INTERES SOCIAL"))
            || (message.Text.Equals("3.- CUV Media")) || (message.Text.Equals("3.- cuv media")) || (message.Text.Equals("3.- CUV MEDIA")) || (message.Text.Equals("3.-")) || (message.Text.Equals("3"))
            || (message.Text.Equals("CUV Media")) || (message.Text.Equals("cuv media")) || (message.Text.Equals("CUV MEDIA")))
        {
            if ((message.Text.Equals("1.- CUV Residencial")) || (message.Text.Equals("1.- cuv residencial")) || (message.Text.Equals("1.- CUV RESIDENCIAL")) || (message.Text.Equals("1"))
            || (message.Text.Equals("1.-")) || (message.Text.Equals("CUV residencial")) || (message.Text.Equals("cuv residencial")) || (message.Text.Equals("CUV RESIDENCIAL")))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("1");
            }
            else if ((message.Text.Equals("2.- CUV de Interes Social")) || (message.Text.Equals("2.- cuv de interes Social")) || (message.Text.Equals("2.- CUV DE INTERES SOCIAL")) || (message.Text.Equals("2"))
            || (message.Text.Equals("2.-")) || (message.Text.Equals("CUV de Interes Social")) || (message.Text.Equals("cuv de interes Social")) || (message.Text.Equals("CUV DE INTERES SOCIAL")))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("2");
            }
            else if ((message.Text.Equals("3.- CUV Media")) || (message.Text.Equals("3.- cuv media")) || (message.Text.Equals("3.- CUV MEDIA")) || (message.Text.Equals("3.-")) || (message.Text.Equals("3"))
            || (message.Text.Equals("CUV Media")) || (message.Text.Equals("cuv media")) || (message.Text.Equals("CUV MEDIA")))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("3");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Opcion no Valida");
            await context.PostAsync("Por favor, selecciona el numero de la opcion que deseas consultar.");
            await context.PostAsync(opcion1CUV + "\n" + "\n" + opcion2CUV + "\n" + "\n" + opcion3CUV);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Don't tag other languages. And please read [ask]

Comment: If you declare a method with a return type (`Task` in this case), then you need a `return` statement in the method body (all code paths must return a value). You can change the return type to `void` if you don't want to return something. Otherwise, I don't think I understand the question.

Comment: Please explain "can't leave the if statement". If statements don't block, they just change the control flow. I recomend pausing in a debugger and understanding what exactly your application is waiting for.

Comment: Hi, this code is quite unreadable... but this is not a complete example.
You're using Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.0? If I look at the [IDialogContext Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.idialogcontext?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0&viewFallbackFrom=botbuilder-dotnet-stable), it seems `PostAsync` needs an IMessageActivity input... as in `var replyMessage = context.MakeMessage();`, `await context.PostAsync(replyMessage);`. I found some code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files)

Answer (score 1):

You achieve your logic with only one level of `if`s.

```
if
else if 
else if 
else
```

Also, take the advantage of string's `.ToLower()`

Once you make these changes it may be easier to debug what the problem is.

---

## Step 2

```
string t = message.Text.ToLower();
if (t.StartsWith("1") || t.Contains("CUV Residencial".ToLower()))
{
    await context.PostAsync("1");
}
else if (t.StartsWith("2") || t.Contains("CUV de Interes Social".ToLower()))
{
    await context.PostAsync("2");
}
else if (t.StartsWith("3") || t.Contains("CUV Media".ToLower()))
{
    await context.PostAsync("3");
}
else
{
    await context.PostAsync("Opcion no Valida");
    (...)
}
```

## Step 1

```
string t = message.Text.ToLower();

        if ((t == "1.- CUV Residencial".ToLower()) || (t == "1".ToLower())
        || (t == "1.-".ToLower()) || (t == "CUV residencial".ToLower()))
        {
            await context.PostAsync("1");
        }
        else if ((t == "2.- CUV de Interes Social".ToLower()) || (t == "2".ToLower())
        || (t == "2.-".ToLower()) || (t == "CUV de Interes Social".ToLower()))
        {
            await context.PostAsync("2");
        }
        else if ((t == "3.- CUV Media".ToLower()) || (t == "3.-".ToLower()) || (t == "3".ToLower())
        || (t == "CUV Media".ToLower()))
        {
            await context.PostAsync("3");
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Opcion no Valida");
            (...)
        }
```